# Running "bundle exec jazzy" returns error

Tags: xcode, jazzy

I try to run jazzy for my project in xcode 11.3 and I get

Running xcodebuild
Could not successfully run `xcodebuild`.
Please check the build arguments.
bundler: failed to load command: jazzy
RuntimeError: /Users/germanmendoza/Desktop/CI-Demo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/bin/sourcekitten ["doc", "--"]

Failed to generate documentation

And the log has

```
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from disk
Ld /Users/germanmendoza/Desktop/CI-Demo/build/Release-iphoneos/CI-Demo.app/CI-Demo normal arm64 (in target 'CI-Demo' from project 'CI-Demo')
    cd /Users/germanmendoza/Desktop/CI-Demo

ld: framework not found Pods_CI_Demo
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/germanmendoza/Desktop/CI-Demo/build/Release-iphoneos/CI-Demo.app/CI-Demo normal arm64
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like @German said - Running it with parameters might solve the issue.

Here is another parameter example to try:

```
jazzy \
    --clean \
    --author YourName \
    --xcodebuild-arguments -workspace,YourAppName.xcworkspace,-scheme,YourSchemeName \
    --output docs/swift_output
```

### A few things to note:

- If you don't know what a **Scheme** is, chances are, your scheme name is the same as your app's name.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug running jazzy command with parameters

`jazzy --min-acl internal -x -workspace,KavakContent.xcworkspace,-scheme,KavakContent`

And the documentation was generated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it really worked with *Xcode 11.5 beta 2 (11N605f)*
Think to put it more clearly, that's what the line should be called:

```
jazzy --min-acl internal-x -workspace,PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace,-scheme,PROJECT_NAME
```